agular guard completes before checking the value of ngrx selector
I have a guard which needs to check the value in ngrx selector before activating a route.
If no value in the state, then we need to navigate somewhere else.
I have two problems here.
First is that i kind of got solved, that when checking the value in ngrx selector with subscribe, the guard completes before we execute the code in the subscription
the second problem is how can i get the guard to navigate, if no value
now in the mergeMap i can check if value in the state, but if not, i cannot create url tree so i did it to return Observable of false so the code compiles.
In that case, the guard does not activate the route, but i do not know how to navigate in this case
*
export const isLoggedGuard: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
):
  | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
  | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
  | boolean
  | UrlTree => {
  return inject(Store)
    .select(userSelector)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((user: UserInterface | null) => (user ? of(true) : of(false))),
      catchError(() => [inject(Router).createUrlTree(['/'])])
    );
};




If I do:
    let isLogged = false;
    loggedSelector.subscribe((isLoggedSelectorValue: boolean ) => {
   islogged = isLoggedSelectorValue }

the guard completes before we go into the subscribe

You were on the right track with your code, you just need minor updates. The reason why catchError was not triggering is, that no error occurred. Return of(false) is valid, you would have to throw a new error instead. But that's not needed, see below:
// isLoggedGuard accept Observable<boolean | UrlTree> as a return value.
export const isLoggedGuard: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> => {
  return inject(Store)
    .select(userSelector)
    .pipe(
      // No need for the mergeMap and faking with of()
      // Use map operator and either return true, or the UrlTree
      map((user: UserInterface | null) => (user ? true : inject(Router).createUrlTree(["/"]))),
    );
};

And a short note about your second snippet. Since it's incomplete, I'm just guessing but I reckon that you tried doing something like this:
export const isLoggedGuard: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): boolean => {
   let isLogged = false;
   // Observable might be asynchronous. So even if you subscribe like below
   loggedSelector.subscribe((isLoggedSelectorValue: boolean ) => {
     // This line won't be executed as the next one
     islogged = isLoggedSelectorValue }
   );
   // This return statement will be executed next, returning false. 
   // Regardless of what WOULD happen in subscribe, because it happens after the return.
   return isLogged;
};


Thanks that works. The only think is that the inject(Router) inside of the map triggers and error so router has to be injected before the return clause !
Thanks
